# Basic Android App not working on Xamarin Android Player via VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have been trying to run basic Android App provided by Visual Studio 2015 via XAMARIN Android Player. Program gets build and deployed successfully, yet, App or anything does not appear on screen. Xamarin Player takes more than 20 mins to start and then nothing happens. Find Screenshots as well.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post your verbose log output? https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-how-to-collect-version-information-and-logs#verbose-build-output-logs

Comment: here is the link for verbose log:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8h3ozy52ibpmeu/android_logcat.txt?dl=0

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that Windows 10 Professional has Hyper-V enabled by default. Xamarin Android Player's hardware acceleration (through VirtualBox) uses a different virtualization technology that doesn't work when Hyper-V is enabled, so it will run without hardware acceleration in that environment. This could account for the "more than 20 mins to start." In contrast, the Visual Studio Android Emulator (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) uses Hyper-V virtualization, so it should start more quickly.

Comment: I tried installing VS Android enumlator, but, it shows everytime, system requirements not met. Nt able to install.

Comment: Well, I got Hyper-V disabled as well, but, it did not work out well. It is still taking same amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIthin the `Android SDK Manager` look under `Extras` there is an package called `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)`. Installing HAXM will increase the speed of the emulator when you use the `Intel Atom` CPU/ABI

Also when creating the emulator device check `Use Host GPU` for increaded performance.

[image: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator HAXM]

Comment: It surely does accelerate. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into few issues with Xamarin Android Player as well. Currently I am using Genymotion Emulator and it is much faster.

Comment: I l try using this, and  get back!

Answer (score 0):

Well, Well, Well, I got my thing up and running. Following are the steps I performed:

1. After installing Xamarin for VS2015, I checked for latest Android SDK via SDK Manager. Got all the necessary updates installed.
2. Installed Xamarin Android Player and used emulator Nexus 5 KitKat API level 19.
   **Earlier I was using Nexus 5 Lollipop, was the reason why, it was not working. May be its not fixed for buil yet.**
3. As, described by Mr.Pilatus in above answer, the particular HAXM things surely does help in accelerating emulator.
4. Got my Android app running.

Thank you all for all the necessary suggestion and guiding my in my baby steps in XAMARIN development. Gracias. NAMASTE!